# What am I doing wrong that I keep getting this error message?

Tags: sqlplus

Run sqlplus system/Oracle11 and SPOOL to c:\cis4210\M8spool.txt User SCOTT, which had the password TIGER, changed the password to something more secure, but has since forgotten it.

If possible, demonstrate what you as a DBA can do to give SCOTT access to his account.

Other users need access to the tables belonging to IGGY.

Create a role named CLERK that has SELECT privileges for tables PART, SUPPLIER, and QUOTE.

Assign the role CLERK to user SCOTT.

Connect as user SCOTT and `SELECT * FROM QUOTE` to demonstrate that SCOTT has access to IGGY’s tables.

This is what I have!

```
SQL>alter user SCOTT identified by "TIGER" account unlock;
User altered.

SQL>conn Scott/TIGER
Connected.

SQL>Exit

SQL>conn SCOTT/Oracle11
Connected.
SQL> SELECT 'GRANT SELECT"||table_name||'TO other user;'
FROM all tables WHERE owner = 'IGGY';
no rows selected

SQL> GRANT SELECT ON iggy.PART TO clerk;
ERROR at line 1:
ORA - 00942: table or view does not exist

This is the problem I am having!
SQL> GRANT SELECT ON iggy.SUPPLIER TO clerk;
SQL> GRANT SELECT ON iggy.QUOTE TO clerk;
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a role named CLERK that has SELECT privileges for tables PART, SUPPLIER, and QUOTE.

```
SQL> CREATE ROLE CLERK NOT IDENTIFIED ; 

SQL> GRANT SELECT ON IGGY.PART to CLERK ;
SQL> GRANT SELECT ON IGGY.SUPPLIER TO CLERK; 
SQL> GRANT SELECT ON IGGY.QUOTE TO CLERK ;
```

So, the exercise is telling you to create a role name CLERK, and then assign SELECT over the tables to the ROLE.

Assign the role CLERK to user SCOTT.

```
SQL> GRANT CLERK TO SCOTT ;
```

You must create the role with a user who posses the create role privilege, normally a dba user as system should do this.

Then you only need to connect with SCOTT, who has been granted with the role CLERK, and therefore has inherited the select over the tables, and do a select of any of the tables before mentioned